# SQL query from PHP to AZURE with where included

Tags: php, azure

This is a simple SQL query and it works. I'm forced to use the "" around the field user or else it crashes:

```
$SqlCheck = 'SELECT * from "user"';
```

Now i want to use a `Where` in it.

```
$SqlCheck = 'SELECT * from "user" WHERE "user_email" LIKE ' . $user . ';
```

Also tried `where a = b` but it doesn't like the = and it works with `LIKE`.

Since there's so many mixed up between " and ' ... Nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Garrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr I knew it was simple... after to many hours of bashing my head into the wall.

```
$SqlCheck = 'SELECT * from "user"
WHERE "user_email" LIKE \'' . $user . '\'
AND "user_password" LIKE  \'' . $pass . '\'';
```